Help for inventing Hilbert-style deduction system for a language containing many logical connectives and quantifiers
The challenge is the following: Create a formal deduction system consisting of Modus Ponens (MP) as the sole inference rule for a language containing the following symbols:
¬ (not)
∧ (and)
∨ (or)
→ (implies)
↔ (iff)
← (is implied by)
∃ (there exists)
∀ (for all)
↑ (nand)
↓ (nor)
̸→ (doesn't imply)
̸↔ (isn't equivalent to)
⊕ (xor)
̸← (is not implied by)
̸∃ (there doesn't exist)
̸∀ (not for all)
Here's my attempt:
I've started with the following axiom schemes:
(A1): A→(B→A)
(A2): (A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))
(A3): (¬A→¬B)→(B→A)
(A4): ∀xA(x)→A(c), where A(c) is the formula obtained by replacing each occurrence of the bound variable x in A(x) by c
(A5): ∀x(A(x)→B(x))→(∀xA(x)→∀xB(x))
(A6): A→∀xA if x isn't free in A
From those, I should manage to prove all tautologies using only ¬, → and ∀. I'm well aware that one could simply use the other connectives/quantifiers as abbreviations in the metalanguage, but that would be against the rules of the challenge. I've thought of introducing the definitions of the other symbols as logical axiom schemes, like for example (A∨B)↔(¬A→B), ∃xA(x)↔¬∀x¬A(x), etc. My idea was to then to use a rule like substitution to replace subformulas by equivalent formulas, but to use MP as the only inference rule (another constraint for the challenge), I would need to prove the substitution rule, but I'm having trouble doing it (I'm not sure what logical axioms are required to prove it).
I'm looking forward to seeing your attempts or reading your suggestions!

SEP entry on Intuitionistic Logic has the full set of axioms for the main connectives. The additional ones, like e.g. XOR and NAND can be managed with the usual definitions through a pair of axioms for introducing and eliminating them.

Note that your contraposition axiom makes no sense. Instead of (¬A→¬B)→(A→B), you want (¬A→¬B)→(B→A).

Ups, you're right, I've mistyped. I'll edit that

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA thaks, I'll check on that
